# Hibernate : em.getReference().getList().add(record) performance?

Tags: performance, hibernate, jpa

When using Hibernate (JPA), if I do the following call :

```
MyParent parent = em.getReference("myId");
parent.getAListMappedAsOneToMany().add(record) 
record.setParent(parent);
```

Is there any performance problem ?

My thoughts is that `getReference` does not load the entity and `getAListeMappedAsOneToMany().add` do not need to load the list as it is defined as lazy fetch.

`getAListMappedAsOneToMany` could return a very big list if it is really accessed (by calling `get` or `size` method).

Could you confirm that there is no performance problem with such a code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getReference()` doesn't go to the database, and returns a proxy. But if you call a method on the proxy, it initializes the proxy and gets the entity data from the database. So since you call `getAListMappedAsOneToMany()` on your entity, you don't gain anything by calling `getReference()` instead of `find()`.

Similarly, the list is loaded lazily. this means that it will only be loaded when you call a method on it. And you do call a method on it: `add()`. So the data of the elements in the list is also loaded from the database.

Turn on SQL logging in devlopment, to see and understand all the queries executed by Hibernate.

If you want to avoid loading the list, replace your code by

```
MyParent parent = em.getReference("myId");
record.setParent(parent);
```

This won't load anything from the database, and it will make the association persistent because Record.parent is the owner side of the association. But beware that this will also make your in-memory object graph inconsistent if the parent has already been loaded before.

Comment: The fact is I have activated sql logging and I see no sql query when doing getReference().getAlist().add() (but I see other sql queries, so the log is running well). So, I don't understand...

Comment: Are you sure you have not loaded the objects before in the same session?

Comment: Um, you're right, this was at the beginning of my log. So there is performance impact doing so... (PS : I've just look at your blog, i'm N3, N4 too hard for me for the moment, great job !)

Answer (score 1):

`getReference()` is useful when you don't want to use any members of the object but to give the reference of the object to another object. For example, when entity A referencing entity B and you want to set your b as B of A, then `getReference()` is what you need.

But in your case, when you get the proxy object, you immediately try to reach one of its members. (`aListMappedAsOneToMany`) Thus this will result, the whole `parent` object will be loaded from db.

It is true that, when you `getAListMappedAsOneToMany().add(record)`, it will not load from db yet only if you set `inverse="true"`

You can learn more information about performance from:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-collections-mostefficentinverse